# Assign default value to TIMESTAMP_NTZ snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl

I need to assign default value to column SERVERTIME with datatype TIMESTAMP_NTZ in snowflake.
I have a below query:-

```
CREATE TABLE STG_ORDER_DETAIL
   (    
    ORDERID NUMBER(38,0) not null, 
    ORDER_TYPE VARCHAR(3), 
    AGGRID VARCHAR(20), 
    AGGRNAME VARCHAR(250), 
    MERCHANTID VARCHAR(20) not null, 
    SERVERTIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    CURRENCY VARCHAR(5),
    constraint STG_ORDER_DETAIL_PK primary key (ORDERID, MERCHANTID) not enforced);
```

getting syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the data type is included and matched with the expression:

```
CREATE TABLE STG_ORDER_DETAIL
   (    
    ORDERID NUMBER(38,0) not null, 
    ORDER_TYPE VARCHAR(3), 
    AGGRID VARCHAR(20), 
    AGGRNAME VARCHAR(250), 
    MERCHANTID VARCHAR(20) not null, 
    SERVERTIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    CURRENCY VARCHAR(5),
    constraint STG_ORDER_DETAIL_PK primary key (ORDERID, MERCHANTID) not enforced);
```